# Payment Gateways which supports Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am still new to **Xamarin Forms** and I am looking for a payment gateway to integrate into my app that will work for both Android and IOS platforms at the same time. Any suggestions for the list of payment gateways I could use on the app?

Answer (score 3):

Payment should generally be handled server-side due to the myriad of security concerns that occur in client-side payment processing. What you may notice when going to a payment portal on mobile is that you are going ***to a portal***. You are temporarily redirected to a server-rendered page with a webhook listening for changes in the payment status, terminating the process if details are incorrect or no payment attempt is made after X seconds.

So what I would recommend doing is creating a small independent web application with a small API. This API should make use of a service such as Stripe, and if you want to keep it in dotnet, you can use Stripe's .Net SDK - https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=dotnet.

First, validate your user using some kind of backend authentication check (like bearer token authentication), then redirect the user to the payment portal. Create a webhook with the Stripe webhook API and listen for the payment confirmation (this will likely be done using 3D secure or something similar, where the bank may require the user to confirm the payment on their banking app - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure). With the payment confirmed, you can now actually process the payment.

So TLDR, create a microservice that makes use of the Stripe API. Call this API from Xamarin Forms using HttpClient and authenticate the user. Redirect the user to the payment portal and await the user's payment confirmation with 3D secure. Finally, process and collect the user's payment through the Stripe API.